# Access AuthenticationStateProvider in Blazor Server Side in Custom Class

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there any general guidance on how to access AuthenticationStateProvider in Blazor Server Side in custom classes?  Should AuthenticationStateProvider be added as a singleton service?  Any other way to get it with DI?  I'm not talking about using AuthorizeViews or through cascading parameter.  I need to be able to get AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() in a custom class, rather than a controller, view, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the info Isaac, but I actually was able to answer my own question.  My resolution was to make sure my helper class is scoped and not singleton in order to get an instance of the authstateprovider.

```
services.AddScoped<Classes.GlobalHelper>();
```

I could then call authstateprovider the same as any other DI, for example:

```
public async Task<HttpClient> MyHttpClient()
{
    AuthenticationState _authstate = _authStateProv.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;

    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    string signedInUserID = _authstate.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

Comment: Why do you call Result ? You should await the call to GetAuthenticationStateAsync. Calling Result  is wrong and blocking.

Comment: pasted the code before I finalized... yah... awaiting.

Comment: Those who are interested in an answer to the above question:https://stackoverflow.com/a/62529030/6152891