# No Bearer token in Request Headers

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

using Blazor 3.2 I need to automatically send the security token in request header,I don't use Identity,I have custom tables on the server for users,I get the token from login controller and save it to local storage

```
public class JWTAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider, ILoginService
    {
        private readonly IJSRuntime js;
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private readonly string TOKENKEY = "TOKENKEY";
        private AuthenticationState Anonymous => new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));

        public JWTAuthenticationStateProvider(IJSRuntime js, HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.js = js;
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var token = await js.GetFromLocalStorage(TOKENKEY);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                return Anonymous;
            }
            return BuildAuthenticationState(token);
        }

        public AuthenticationState BuildAuthenticationState(string token)
        {
     
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(token), "jwt")));
        }



        public async Task Login(string token)
        {
            await js.SetInLocalStorage(TOKENKEY, token);
            var authState = BuildAuthenticationState(token);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(authState));
        }

        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await js.RemoveItem(TOKENKEY);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(Anonymous));
        }
    }
```

for requests I use:

```
public interface IHttpService
    {...
        Task<HttpResponseWrapper<object>> Post<T>(string url, T data);
      ...       
    }
    public class HttpService : IHttpService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
        private JsonSerializerOptions DefaultJsonSerializerOptions =>
             new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

        public HttpService(HttpClient _httpClient)
        {
            httpClient = _httpClient;
        }


    .......   

        public async Task<HttpResponseWrapper<object>> Post<T>(string url, T data)
        {
            var dataJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            var stringContent = new StringContent(dataJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
            return new HttpResponseWrapper<object>(null, response.IsSuccessStatusCode, response);
        }

.........

public class HttpResponseWrapper<T>
    { 
        public HttpResponseWrapper(T response, bool succes, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
        {
            Response = response;
            Success = succes;
            HttpResponseMessage = httpResponseMessage;
        }
        public T Response { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage { get; set; }

        public async Task<string> GetBody()
        {
            return await HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

when I send a request to the server :

```
 var res = await httpService.Post<QueryObject, ResObject>($"{url}/get", query);
```

I get 401(Unauthorized), in dev tools i see no Bearer token in Request

> Headers: :authority: localhost:44341 :method: POST :path:
> /api/datar/get :scheme: https accept: / accept-encoding: gzip,
> deflate, br accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9 cache-control: no-cache
> content-length: 123 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> cookie: .AspNet.Consent=yes;
> .AspNetCore.Session=CfDJ8KV1S2nC4ehItE9KmaCETAilfhhNr%2BP3SQORWHzxbFYQLddeekAftj05md7N%2BWYjU1LxdcIBY4XW9muw13u2q2clwdsmQHLb2DqCKkQW%2FbcquzDPKYbcAtcuJEJ2OpOz75zgMYhRmL47zGhNvmhhHXbEEKGnQwpAk8gnAe6bF6XC
> origin: https://localhost:44341 pragma: no-cache referer:
> https://localhost:44341/sch sec-fetch-dest: empty sec-fetch-mode: cors
> sec-fetch-site: same-origin user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
> Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.80
> Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.148

Comment: See this linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62529030/6152891

Comment: that's what I've already done is above code,save token to local storage then automatically call GetAuthenticationStateAsync and add it to header: httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token)

Comment: No, your code is doing it differently and wrongly. In my code you read the Jwt token from the local storage immediately before it is used in an HTTP call. In your code you create an AuthenticationHeaderValue object containing the bearer token, which might be stale and invalid by the time you perform a new HTTP call. This is wrong. The design is badly made. And this is not your code. I know who's the author of this code sample. I've started learning Blazor is his WebSite. I really appreciate him, but I think it's high time this sample is pensioned off, especially because you can use the new

Comment: authentication and authorization api provided by the Blazor team

Comment: you're right,If I move   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token) from GetAuthenticationStateAsync() just before any request made by HttpService,it works fine.I see the same as my old code in may examples from google,one is there: https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity

Comment: I'd advise you to pension off this stuff, and instead invest your time in learning the new stuff. This does not mean that what you've learned so far was useless and a waste of time of course; just that you must proceed to the new authentication and authorization api that would really render your capable of creating a full-fledged Blazor app. Good luck.