# Custom AuthenticationStateProvider in blazor project doesn't work on server side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side

**Hi all!**
I'm trying to make my custom auth mode in Blazor WebAssembly App (this is where studio creates 3 projects - client, server, shared). Idea is avoid IS4 auth and make my oun "internal" user for test purposes and understand the work of auth mech as well. I'm doing it by creating my custom AuthenticationStateProvider? like it shown in [official docs](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/blazor/security/index.md#implement-a-custom-authenticationstateprovider-1). This is my AuthenticationStateProvider class:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private bool _isLoggedIn = true;

    //this is a parameter defininng whether user logged in or not
    //changed by reflection
    public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get
        {
            return _isLoggedIn;
        }
        set
        {
            _isLoggedIn = value;
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
        }
    }
    private static CustomAuthStateProvider _myInstance = null;



    public Serilog.ILogger _logger { get; set; }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity;

        Task<AuthenticationState> rez;

     if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "User01"),
            }, "Fake authentication type");
        }
        else
        {
            identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        }
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        rez = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));

        return rez;

    }

    public static CustomAuthStateProvider GetMyInstance(Serilog.ILogger logger = null, string mySide = "")
    {
        //implementing singleton
        if (_myInstance == null)
        {
            _myInstance = new CustomAuthStateProvider();
            _myInstance._logger = logger;
        }
        return _myInstance;
    }
}
```

This is how i plug it on client side (program.cs)

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider>(x => CustomAuthStateProvider.GetMyInstance(Log.Logger, "Client"));
```

This is how i plug it on server side (startup.cs)

```
services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
```

**Problem:**
it works fine on client side, that means i can login, logout and use AutorizeView and similar tags. But It doesnt' t work on server side, that means HttpContext.User doesn't see any user authenticated and i cant use [Authorize] and similar attributes. What i'm doing wrong? How HttpContext.User is connected to AuthenticationStateProvider in asp.net core project?
Thanks ;-)

Comment: Found similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529029/customizing-the-authenticationstateprovider-in-blazor-server-app-with-jwt-token/62529030#62529030

Comment: I think the services registration should be Scoped.  I've also added the code for my server side authorization tester below for you.  I've added it as an answer as that's the only way to add it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a very simple Test AuthenticationStateProvider I hashed up recently for a Server Side project.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blazor.Auth.Test
{
    public class TestAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {

        public TestUserType UserType { get; private set; } = TestUserType.None;

        private ClaimsPrincipal Admin
        {
            get
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "985fdabb-5e4e-4637-b53a-d331a3158680"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Administrator"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
                }, "Test authentication type");
                return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            }
        }

        private ClaimsPrincipal User
        {
            get
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "024672e0-250a-46fc-bd35-1902974cf9e1"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Normal User"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User")
                }, "Test authentication type");
                return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            }
        }

        private ClaimsPrincipal Visitor
        {
            get
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "3ef75379-69d6-4f8b-ab5f-857c32775571"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Visitor"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Visitor")
                }, "Test authentication type");
                return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            }
        }

        private ClaimsPrincipal Anonymous
        {
            get
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "0ade1e94-b50e-46cc-b5f1-319a96a6d92f"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Anonymous"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Anonymous")
                }, null);
                return new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            }
        }

        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var task = this.UserType switch
            {
                TestUserType.Admin => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Admin)),
                TestUserType.User => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.User)),
                TestUserType.None => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Anonymous)),
                _ => Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(this.Visitor))
            };
            return task;
        }

        public Task<AuthenticationState> ChangeUser(TestUserType userType)
        {
            this.UserType = userType;
            var task = this.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            this.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(task);
            return task;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blazor.Auth.Test
{
    public enum TestUserType
    {
        None,
        Visitor,
        User,
        Admin
    }
}
```

Startup regstration:

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, TestAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

Simple Component I add to NavMenu to switch users.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="m-1 p-1 text-white">
            @user.Identity.Name
        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <div class="m-1 p-1 text-white">
            Not Logged In
        </div>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
<div class="m-1 p-3">
    <select class="form-control" @onchange="ChangeUser">
        @foreach (var value in Enum.GetNames(typeof(TestUserType)))
        {
            <option value="@value">@value</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter] public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthTask { get; set; }

    [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider AuthState { get; set; }

    private System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal user;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthTask;
        this.user = authState.User;
    }

    private async Task ChangeUser(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var en = Enum.Parse<TestUserType>(e.Value.ToString());
        var authState = await ((TestAuthenticationStateProvider)AuthState).ChangeUser(en);
        this.user = authState.User;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Very thanks for answer)
I did server side as you wrote, changed server Startup regstration to AddScoped, but nothing still changed. In server controllers user has 1 empty identity, thus it's not authenticated and doesnt pass [Autorize] attribute. I continue working over this question. I wander, where HttpContext take user when controller instance is created.

Comment: Are you doing Server Side Blazor, or do you have a WASM application calling a "Server Side" API.  If the second case then the API is pure ASPNetCore, not Blazor at all, and my code above doesn't actual apply!

Comment: @enet very thanks for answer! I've added AuthenticationStateProvider to DI as you wrote 'services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthStateProviderOnServer>());' , and my AuthenticationStateProvider descendant is similar to yours, but nothing changed. Still, i continue working)

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis i'm doing exactly first, this is where you create a blazor web app that consists of Client, Server and Shared prohects

Comment: That's a WASM Blazor application with an API ASPNetCore backend, not a Blazor Server application.  Forget my answer, it's for a Blazor Server application.  Your talking about authenticating the user in the WASM application on the API controllers?

Comment: @enet i'm talking about Blazor WebAssembly App (3 projects).

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis i'm talking about WASM Blazor application with an API ASPNetCore backend (3 projects). Guys, i'm really sorry to trouble anyone, i'm just new to blazor)

Comment: @FedorPinega.  No problem, pretty common to get at cross purposes!  See enet's answer.