# Blazor server authentication

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, blazor, claims

i want add authentication to my blazor server side application. I have this code to login.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Username),
    new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name ?? user.Username),
    new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Sid, user.ID.ToString())
};
if (user.Email != null)
    claims.Add(new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));

if (user.UserRoles != null)
{
    foreach (var userRole in user.UserRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Role, userRole.ID_Role));
    }
}

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    AllowRefresh = _authModel.Value.AllowRefresh,
    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(_authModel.Value.LoginExpirationMinutes),
    IsPersistent = input.IsPersistent
};

await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);
```

Everything looks good. The code normaly runs. But when i watch to the HttpContext.User or AuthenticationStateProvider it's empty. In explorer i don't see cookie. What i do bad?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the authentication internal to your Blazor app or are you doing any API access?

Normally you hand off to an external to the SPA authentication provider who then calls back to your SPA with the `HttpContext.User` set.  The default `AuthenticationStateProvider` then reads the user data from `HttpContext.User`.

You are authenticating internally within the SPA.  The startup page is loaded and `HttpContext.User` already set.  I'm not sure that you can reset it.  You can write a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider`.  Take a look at my answer to question  [Custom AuthenticationStateProvider in blazor project doesn't work on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69519057/custom-authenticationstateprovider-in-blazor-project-doesnt-work-on-server-side/69523448#69523448)  which shows how to build a test `AuthenticationStateProvider`.  You should be able to plug this together with your code.

#### Update

Here's a very dumb `AuthenticationStateProvider` that provides the authentication for two fixed users.  Call `ChangeIdentity` from a button to switch.  You don't need to try and do anything with the `HttpContext`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blazor.Auth.Test
{
    public class DumbAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        public static ClaimsPrincipal User
            => new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(UserClaims, "Dumb Auth Type"));

        public static Claim[] UserClaims
            => new[]{
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "024672e0-250a-46fc-bd35-1902974cf9e1"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Normal User"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "Normal User"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "user@user,com"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User")
            };
        public static ClaimsPrincipal Visitor
            => new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(VisitorClaims, "Dumb Auth Type"));

        public static Claim[] VisitorClaims
            => new[]{
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "324672e0-250a-46fc-bd35-1902974cf9e1"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Visitor"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "Normal Visitor"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "visitor@user,com"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Visitor")
            };

        bool _switch;

        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
            => Task.FromResult(_switch 
                ? new AuthenticationState(User)
                : new AuthenticationState(Visitor)
                );

        public Task<AuthenticationState> ChangeIdentity()
        {
            _switch = !_switch;
            var task = this.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            this.NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(task);
            return task;
        }

    }
}
```

And the services setup in StartUp:

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, DumbAuthenticationStateProvider>();
services.AddAuthorizationCore();
```

```
   <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="ChangeID">Switch</button>

@code {

   [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider {get; set;}

    private DumbAuthenticationStateProvider myAuthenticationStateProvider  => authenticationStateProvider as DumbAuthenticationStateProvider;

    private async Task ChangeID()
    {
        await myAuthenticationStateProvider.ChangeIdentity();
    }
}
```

### Second Update based on GitHub copy of app.

First you need to ensure the new `AuthenticationStateProvider` is loaded after `ServerSideBlazor` (it loads `ServerAuthenticationSateProvider` which overloads whatever has been loaded before) and clean up StartUp:

```
        {
            //services.AddAuthentication(
            //    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            //    .AddCookie();
            // services.AddAuthorization();

            //services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<DumbAuthenticationStateProvider>());

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, DumbAuthenticationStateProvider>();
            services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }
```

Update App.razor - change out `RouteView` for `AuthorizeRouteView`.

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

My Test Page

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

@using WebApplication6.Data
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="m-2 p-2">
            <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>


<button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="ChangeID">Switch</button>

@code {

    [Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider { get; set; }

    private DumbAuthenticationStateProvider myAuthenticationStateProvider => authenticationStateProvider as DumbAuthenticationStateProvider;

    private async Task ChangeID()
    {
        await myAuthenticationStateProvider.ChangeIdentity();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i use Blazor Server Side. I tired your solution and it isnt working...

Comment: See updated answer with a working "dumb" setup you can plug in and use to test.

Comment: Hi, its dont working for me... I do it how you write and myAuthenticationStateProvider is null. But i've noticed that authenticationStateProvider in .razor is from namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider. But im startup and _Imports i have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization. So i don't understand this. Thank you.
Here is the screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/2gCsWXz/Untitled.png

Comment: I tried everything and nothing work...

Comment: If you can, publish your project, or a test project that behaves the same.  to GitHub temporarily.  Your missing something in the project "infrastructure".

Comment: Here is my code https://github.com/petrkasnal/BlazorTest

Comment: See my comments on changes to your repo.  I think I covered everything!

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Problem was order in startup. But still not create cookie in my explorer. So after refresh im "logout".

Comment: I said this was simple and dumb. You can persist the state either with a cookie or local storage.  You also need to build in expiration and refresh.  I'm working on an article and Repo on the subject, but it's not ready yet.

Comment: Ok but idk how to create cookie over this solution. I saw microsoft solution without scaffholding. They solution is used razor pages inside blazor. It's not bad but i thinked better solution will be this. So solution is create cookie over IJsRuntime but idk how create micrisift auth cookie.

Comment: Yes, all the examples use "offsite" authentication, so the cookie gets set in the returned page.  At present I don't know either, it's one of bits I've got to sort out in my article!

Comment: Ok. Can you send me the article when you finished them? Thank you. For this i use razor solution or maybe i try powerful google more :D But i rly dont know how "generate" cookie token and cookie name :/ Thank you very much for your time. The solution was bad order in startup. :)